# TFS merge during build and release

Tags: tfs, deployment, azure-devops, release-management, tfvc

We are using visualstudio.com TFS to store the source code. We have DEV, STG and PROD branches. now I want to automate build and release to IIS server.
But it looks like to me that TFS compiles the code from the branch where I commit to, and that's the only build, after that I can install the same binary on all the servers.
But it doesn't seem to be ok, because what if we find a bug on the live code, so we need to fix it, but we already have new code in DEV, and we don't want to revert, and install the old code with the fix on the dev server?

What I think we should do is to merge the code from DEV to STG, from STG to PROD, but I couldn't find any module for that. And it looks strange, I would be surprised if I am the only person whats to do this, especially because it is doable with Jenkins.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically discourage automating merging of code between branches; merging should be a deliberate action. When someone expresses that desire, it's usually a sign of a problem with the branching model and deployment model they're using.

Code promotion branching (where you have one branch that corresponds to each environment, as in the scenario you described) is a bad practice because it encourages you to build different sets of binaries for each environment. You build something for a lower environment, test it, validate it, then **totally disregard** that testing and rebuild from source. That should terrify you, especially for production branches -- you have no idea if what you just built is going to work properly.

Current thinking is to minimize the number of branches you have, and instead isolate in-progress work behind feature toggles so that features that aren't ready for production can simply be disabled, but still allow deployments to take place. With sufficiently mature feature toggling practices and testing practices in place, you can actually eliminate branching entirely and work out of a single branch, promoting binaries to production whenever your automated and manual QA process deems the version they're testing is good.

Assuming you're using TFVC, if you want to maintain a code promotion branching strategy, then you'll need to maintain multiple builds and releases, one for each branch/environment. Typically, in this kind of scenario, I'd eliminate the stage branch entirely. Anything that goes to the Dev branch is built and deployed to Dev. Anything that goes into the Prod branch is built and follows a deployment pipeline from staging->production. Hotfixes can go directly into the prod branch and be merged backwards. There are tons of strategies for branching; you'll need to [read up on the subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc) and design a branching and release strategy that works best for your team.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Ok so if I understand correctly, I can do this (using the dev isolation):
Have a main branch, and a dev. We commit everything into the dev, it is automatically built, and installed on the dev server. We test. When we are happy with all of the changes in DEV, we manually merge the DEV into the main repo. The main repo is built, and it is installed on the test server, for example. If it still looks good on the test, the same binary can be installed on the prod.

Is that right?

Comment: @barii That's correct. However, there are many possible approaches to this. It's best to do the research and think about not just how your process works today, but how you'd like it to work in the future.